# mount -- how long has a partition been mounted?

Tags: mount

Asides from viewing `dmesg` logs, does mount keep any records of when a partition has been mounted? perhaps viewing the `ctime` of the mount target? Does anyone have a definitive command for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system tools for the filesystem you're using should be able to help you with that.

For example with ext2 / ext3 / ext4 there's `dumpe2fs`:

```
$ sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda1 | grep 'Last mount time'
Last mount time:          Mon Apr 18 18:13:05 2016
```

(where /dev/sda1 is the partition you're interested in)

Comment: Nice! that works. My problem involves finding information about a cifs mount which doesn't appear work with `dumpe2fs`.